# Submit VUE-Array to Laravel with hidden Input

Tags: arrays, laravel, vue.js, object, submit

this is my first forum post, so please be a little tolerant of my language. In addition, I'm still a beginner and may need a little to understand everything :D

I have the following problem:
In my Laravel application I have a V-Calendar Datepicker. Now I want to transfer the selected data to the controller when I click Submit.
My first idea was to write my object array in a hidden input using v-bind:value.
Unfortunately, only a string "[object, object, object]" is transmitted here, instead of an array with objects.

Would you have a suggested solution for me or can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance and have a nice day

DerHaendler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution!

I need to decode the string in Controller with `json_decode($request->input('hidden_input'));`

Have a nice day